# Use Wilson Theorem for the divisor

Tags: real-numbers

*Use **Wilson Theorem** to find the smallest possible number which completely divides **(12! + 6! + 12! × 6! + 1!)**.*

### Wilson Theorem →

Wilson Theorem states that if n is a prime number then ***n*** divides ***[(n-1)!+1]*** completely.

### ***↓↓ Answer Below ↓↓***

.
.
.
.
.
.
.

The answer is **7**

Answer (score 0):

By Wilson's Theorem, $7$ divides $(7-1)!+1 = 6!+1$

$(12! + 6! + 12! × 6! + 1!) = (12! * 6! + 12!) + (6! +1) = (6!+1) * (12!+ 1)$, meaning this giant number will have prime factors $7$ and $13$, because $7$ is the smaller of the two, our answer must be $7$.

Answer (score 0):

1 is trivial

$2,3,4,5,6$ divide $6!$ and $12!$ therefore cannot divide $12! + 6! + 12!\times 6! + 1$ as each would divide the first three terms but not the last.

$7$ divides $12!$ and $12!\times 6!$ and by Wilson's theorem, outlined above, divides $6! + 1  $